# Функция IdnToAscii - слишком много значений инициализатора

Tags: html, c++, http, winsock

Подскажите пожалуйста, что то я не могу понять:

-Вот предположим я сделал GET запрос на сервер.

-Сервер мне ответил и выслал HTML страницу, сооветвенно я принял этот поток байт и записал его в массив.

-Теперь я разбираю http заголовки и вижу, что сервер указал, что кодировка HTML тела - UTF-16.

Вопрос: а как понять, сколько байт занимает этот присланный UTF-16 символ ?
К примеру на Windows - wchar_t занимает 2 байта, на Linux - 4 байта.

И я что то не могу сообразить, вот прислал мне сервер 4 байта в кодировке UTF-16 - как понять - это два символа по 2 байта, или это один символ занимающий 4 бата ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-16 - это всегда два байта на символ.

Вместо дурацкого `wchar_t` (дурацкого - потому что размер зависит от платформы) используйте `char16_t` (и `std::u16string`), или просто `std::uint16_t`.

Comment: спасибо, тут даже дело не в том, что мне использовать, а в том, как мне интерпретировать полученные байты. То есть, если указано UTF-16, то сервер гарантировано пришел именно 2 байта на символ ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Да. Там же не зря число 16 в названии - это количество бит на символ...